# Swift and Xcode: How to Build and Run a GitHub repository of iOS Application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm interested on Running this GitHub repository of an iOS Application: https://github.com/septadev/SEPTA-iOS I opened the iSEPTA.xcodeproj file on XCode from the iSEPTA folder, but I'm getting these Buildtime [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayrjg.png). For example: [No such module 'ReSwift'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdnMw.png), and this is the [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey09I.png) I get prompted when I select any of the yellow alerts, I'm not sure if I should perform these changes, yet.

Could it be some incomparability with my XCode and Swift versions?
Please, help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project uses [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) as a dependency management system for using external dependencies.

You should install Carthage to your computer and then run `carthage update` from the terminal in the root directory of the project. This will instal the dependencies and will allow you to run the project.

Comment: If you will build the project only for iOS platform use ```carthage update --platform ios```command. It will run faster

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Cartfile`: it indicates this repo is using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) package manager. Follow their instructions to install dependent libraries

Answer (score 0):

This repository requires Carthage ( https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage ) - this is a dependency manager. You can install it using Homebrew (https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install carthage
```

then you have to run `carthageBuild.sh` script (which runs `carthage update`):

```
./carthageBuild.sh
```

and then you have to open: `Septa.xcworkspace` file

Answer (score -1):

**This would be the correct solution if the project used Cocoapods. Since it uses Carthage, look to others answers unless you are referencing this answer to a similar issue.**

You need to use Cocoapods to integrate the pods attached to the project. Often times projects will not come with them precompiled. Either you opened the blue project file with the *.xcodeproj extension instead of the white project file with the *.xcworkspace extension.... or you don't have the pods installed at all. In which case read below.

Instructions as follows:

1. **cd to project directory**
2. **Install Cocoapods**

   - `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. **Ensure the you have the given pods in your repo collection for install**

   - `pod repo update`
4. **Install the pods**

   - `pod install`
5. **Validate Project Settings**

   - This is necessary until cocoapods v1.6 release (beta is out).[image]
6. **Open the white project file with the *.xcworkspace extension**

After those steps are complete, the project should run normally.